# How to call web Services in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, web-services, methods

I am calling web services and returning into list but I am not able to do same.
I want to bind drop down list with web services.

I have added INITIATORS_LIST class which contain all field which I want to bind in Drop down list like Companies, Countries, Divisions, Location... So on. How can I achieve any alternate method may I accept please ?

Sample JSON Data

```
{"Companies":[{"ACTIVE":true,"COMPANY_ID":1,"CompanyCode":"1000","CompanyName":"Almarai Company","CountryCode":"SAU","CountryName":"Saudi Arabia","DivisionCode":"1000","DivisionId":1,"DivisionName":"Sales"},{"ACTIVE":true,"COMPANY_ID":6,"CompanyCode":"4000","CompanyName":"Almarai Co. Bahrain WLL","CountryCode":"BAH","CountryName":"Bahrain","DivisionCode":"1000","DivisionId":1,"DivisionName":"Sales"},{"ACTIVE":true,"COMPANY_ID":8,"CompanyCode":"5000","CompanyName":"Bustan Al Khaleej Est.","CountryCode":"UAE","CountryName":"United Arab Emirates","DivisionCode":"1000","DivisionId":1,"DivisionName":"Sales"},{"ACTIVE":true,"COMPANY_ID":11,"CompanyCode":"5200","CompanyName":"ALMARAI EMIRATES COMPANY L.L.C","CountryCode":"UAE","CountryName":"United Arab Emirates","DivisionCode":"1000","DivisionId":1,"DivisionName":"Sales"},{"ACTIVE":true,"COMPANY_ID":15,"CompanyCode":"6000","CompanyName":"Al Kharafi Brothers","CountryCode":"KWT","CountryName":"Kuwait","DivisionCode":"1000","DivisionId":1,"DivisionName":"Sales"},{"ACTIVE":true,"COMPANY_ID":18,"CompanyCode":"7000","CompanyName":"Arabian Planets Company","CountryCode":"OMN","CountryName":"Oman","DivisionCode":"1000","DivisionId":1,"DivisionName":"Sales"}],"Countries":[{"COUNTRY_ACTIVE":true,"COUNTRY_M_ID":1,"CountryCode":"SAU","CountryName":"Saudi Arabia","DivisionCode":"1000","DivisionId":1,"DivisionName":"Sales"},{"COUNTRY_ACTIVE":true,"COUNTRY_M_ID":3,"CountryCode":"UAE","CountryName":"United Arab Emirates","DivisionCode":"1000","DivisionId":1,"DivisionName":"Sales"},{"COUNTRY_ACTIVE":true,"COUNTRY_M_ID":4,"CountryCode":"BAH","CountryName":"Bahrain","DivisionCode":"1000","DivisionId":1,"DivisionName":"Sales"},{"COUNTRY_ACTIVE":true,"COUNTRY_M_ID":5,"CountryCode":"OMN","CountryName":"Oman","DivisionCode":"1000","DivisionId":1,"DivisionName":"Sales"},{"COUNTRY_ACTIVE":true,"COUNTRY_M_ID":7,"CountryCode":"KWT","CountryName":"Kuwait","DivisionCode":"1000","DivisionId":1,"DivisionName":"Sales"}],"Divisions":[{"ACTIVE":true,"CompanyCode":null,"CompanyName":null,"CountryCode":null,"CountryName":null,"DB_CONNECTION_STRING":null,"DivisionCode":"1000","DivisionId":1,"DivisionName":"Sales","WEB_URL":null}],"Locations":
```

ALM_COUNTRY_M class:

```
 public partial class ALM_COUNTRY_M : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, 
        System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
        
        [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private bool COUNTRY_ACTIVEField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private int COUNTRY_M_IDField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string CountryCodeField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string CountryNameField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string DivisionCodeField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private int DivisionIdField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string DivisionNameField;
        
        [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
            get {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public bool COUNTRY_ACTIVE {
            get {
                return this.COUNTRY_ACTIVEField;
            }
            set {
                if ((this.COUNTRY_ACTIVEField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.COUNTRY_ACTIVEField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("COUNTRY_ACTIVE");
                }
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public int COUNTRY_M_ID {
            get {
                return this.COUNTRY_M_IDField;
            }
            set {
                if ((this.COUNTRY_M_IDField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.COUNTRY_M_IDField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("COUNTRY_M_ID");
                }
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string CountryCode {
            get {
                return this.CountryCodeField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.CountryCodeField, value) != true)) {
                    this.CountryCodeField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("CountryCode");
                }
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string CountryName {
            get {
                return this.CountryNameField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.CountryNameField, value) != true)) {
                    this.CountryNameField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("CountryName");
                }
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string DivisionCode {
            get {
                return this.DivisionCodeField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.DivisionCodeField, value) != true)) {
                    this.DivisionCodeField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("DivisionCode");
                }
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public int DivisionId {
            get {
                return this.DivisionIdField;
            }
            set {
                if ((this.DivisionIdField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.DivisionIdField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("DivisionId");
                }
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string DivisionName {
            get {
                return this.DivisionNameField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.DivisionNameField, value) != true)) {
                    this.DivisionNameField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("DivisionName");
                }
            }
        }
        
        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

INITIATORS_LIST Class:

```
public partial class INITIATORS_LIST : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
        
        [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COMPANY_M[] CompaniesField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COUNTRY_M[] CountriesField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_DIVISION_M[] DivisionsField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.LOCATION[] LocationsField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.REGION[] RegionsField;
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_WKFLW_TYPE_M[] WorkflowTypesField;
        
        [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
            get {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COMPANY_M[] Companies {
            get {
                return this.CompaniesField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.CompaniesField, value) != true)) {
                    this.CompaniesField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Companies");
                }
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COUNTRY_M[] Countries {
            get {
                return this.CountriesField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.CountriesField, value) != true)) {
                    this.CountriesField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Countries");
                }
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_DIVISION_M[] Divisions {
            get {
                return this.DivisionsField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.DivisionsField, value) != true)) {
                    this.DivisionsField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Divisions");
                }
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.LOCATION[] Locations {
            get {
                return this.LocationsField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.LocationsField, value) != true)) {
                    this.LocationsField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Locations");
                }
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.REGION[] Regions {
            get {
                return this.RegionsField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.RegionsField, value) != true)) {
                    this.RegionsField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Regions");
                }
            }
        }
        
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_WKFLW_TYPE_M[] WorkflowTypes {
            get {
                return this.WorkflowTypesField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.WorkflowTypesField, value) != true)) {
                    this.WorkflowTypesField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("WorkflowTypes");
                }
            }
        }
        
        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Reference:

```
public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.INITIATORS_LIST GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(string userId, string WorkflowTypeCode) {
            return base.Channel.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userId, WorkflowTypeCode);
        }

[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IMasterDataService/GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IMasterDataService/GetInitiatorsListByWorkflowResponse")]
        [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.CustomFaultException), Action="http://tempuri.org/IMasterDataService/GetInitiatorsListByWorkflowCustomFaultExcep" +
            "tionFault", Name="CustomFaultException", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Almarai.Web.Services.MasterData")]
        Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.INITIATORS_LIST GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(string userId, string WorkflowTypeCode);
```

Country class: (Should I change this class for Each different field like Company, Country, Region....so on)

```
public class CountryList
        {
            public CountryList(INITIATORS_LIST data)
            {
                ExtensionData = data;
            }

            public INITIATORS_LIST ExtensionData { get; internal set; }
        }
```

My Method: (How should I modify my method)

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static List<CountryList> GetCountriesName(string UserID)
        {
            GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient();
            string userid = "approver01";
            string work = "4";
            List<CountryList> countries = oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userid, work); // Error on this line 

            foreach (Country c in countries)
            {
                lst.Add(c.Name);
            }

            return lst; //Error on this line
        }
```

I am not able to Add into list is there other approch ?
I know due to return type am not able to do but

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221911/discussion-on-question-by-user14304386-how-to-call-web-services-in-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow method returns a `Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.INITIATORS_LIST` object, not a `List<CountryList>`. Likewise your `GetCountriesName` method returns `List<CountryList>`, not whatever the type of your (undefined in the code shown) `lst` variable is. That's why you have errors - you can't just randomly assign objects to variables which are the wrong type.

Anyway it seems that for your countries list you actually want to use two properties from the `ALM_COUNTRY_M` class. The `INITIATORS_LIST` contains an array of objects of that type.

So what you really need to do is get the array of `ALM_COUNTRY_M` objects from the `INITIATORS_LIST` returned by the `GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow` method, and loop through them, and for each one, create an equivalent instance of `CountryList`, set its properties using the values in the `ALM_COUNTRY_M` object, and add that to the list to be returned.

Something like this (untested):

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<CountryList> GetCountriesName(string UserID)
{
    GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient();
    string userid = "approver01";
    string work = "4";

    Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.INITIATORS_LIST initiatorsList = oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userid, work); //get data from webservice
    Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COUNTRY_M[] countryMList = initiatorsList.Countries; //get list of countries from the data returned by the webservice

    List<CountryList> countries = new List<CountryList>(); //create an empty list which will be populated with data from the webservice

    //loop through list of countries returned from webservice
    foreach (Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COUNTRY_M country in countryMList)
    {
       //add new instance of CountryList using fields from the webservice class
       countries.Add(new CountryList() {
         CountryCode = country.CountryCode,
         CountryName = country.CountryName
       });
    }

    return countries; //return the completed list of countries
}
```

The CountryList class should be defined more like this:

```
public class CountryList
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

}
```

P.S. It would be more meaningful to rename the `CountryList` class to `Country`, since each object only represents a single country. It's the `List<>` part which defines a list. But that's a separate issue for you to decide.